# CSS Box Shadows

Tags: css, box-shadow

Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong in the CSS code below, I want to learn and I want to make what is in the attached image.
The instructions are:
Styles:

- width: 400 px,
- height: 100 px,
- background color: **beige**,
- shadow - centered, 5 px blur, 5 px shadow width, color rgba (0,0,0,0.3),
- horizontally centered text, font size 50 px, moved 20 px from the top, font weight 700,
- rounding corners: 20 px.

My code

```
.test {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: beige;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    box-shadow: inset 5 5 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)}
```

Thank you

Comment: Your box shadow property is defined incorrectly. You need to use units for the numbers, ie `inset 5px 5px 5px...`

Comment: I attached an image but I don't know what happened to id, I made a new post on Imgur https://imgur.com/gallery/jMudhd5, I changed the 5 to px. The shadow only on 2 sides and the txt isn't centered I think is the "text moved **20px** from the top" part

Comment: if the shadow is centered, then first two values are 0 , it would be `0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow#Syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
.test {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: beige;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)}
```

Added padding-top for your requirement of text being moved 20 px from the top. This has everything else you need I believe.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers

Comment: You are certainly welcome. Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it helped. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try:
box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);